# Structure of one tooth less

Tags: structure

> The boy had one tooth less than his sister.

I understand this sentence in meaning. For example if the boy has 30 teeth girl has 31 teeth. But what I couldn’t understand is the structure of “one tooth less” . Is this a noun it seems to me one tooth is an adverb which modifies the adjective less but if it so I can’t answer what the boy has . I mean there is no “something“ the boy has.

Answer (score 2):

"One tooth less" is not grammatically correct, which is why you are having difficulty with it; it should be "one less tooth." But actually that is also incorrect because "tooth" is a count noun, so the proper adjective is *fewer*:

> The boy had one fewer tooth than his sister [did].

**One fewer** is an adjectival phrase modifying **tooth**.